# Не собирает проект через webpack-dev-server

Tags: javascript, webpack

Есть конфиг webpack:

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path    = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry    : { app: [path.join(__dirname, '/src/index.js')] },
  output   : {
    path     : path.resolve(__dirname, 'public/'),
    filename : 'bundle.js'
  },
  devtool: 'source-map',

  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test    : /\.js$/,
        exclude : [/node_modules/, /public/],
        loader  : 'babel',
        query   : {
          presets: ['es2015']
        }
      },
      {
        test    : /\.css$/,
        loader  : "style-loader!css-loader!autoprefixer-loader",
        exclude : [/node_modules/, /public/]
      },
    ]
  },

  devServer: {
    contentBase: 'public'
  },
  devServer: {
    proxy: {
      '*': {
        target: 'http://127.0.0.1:3000/',
        secure: false
      }
    }
  },
  proxy: {
    '*': {
      target: 'http://127.0.0.1:3000/',
      secure: false
    }
  }
}
```

Если запускаю через команду webpack, то проект собирается.

Если запускаю через команду webpack-dev-server проект не собирается, в чем проблема ?

Answer (score 1):

У Вас кажется в настройках два свойства devServer.

```
devServer: {
    contentBase: 'public'
},
devServer: {
    proxy: {
      '*': {
        target: 'http://127.0.0.1:3000/',
        secure: false
      }
    }
},
```

Объедините их